# Android – java, send location-data from a class toward and activity-view

Tags: android, class, location

please help me with this, I´m working with android studio – java. I have an Activity(MainActivity) where I want to show the information about location; but I want this information come from other class(Location) toward this MainActivity, how can I make this location class send the location data automatically.
Well, I had try to call the method in MainActivity where I get the location data from class-location, but this methods has parameters “Location location”, so I can’t call it directly.
And I had try put a method inside the “location method” to send the information, but It doesn’t work
I declare the location variables global and put It in other method to send them but doesn’t’ work
I´m trying using the location information (latitude and longitude) from a class using extra, but how can get the data.
Anyway… please help me, the Idea is pass the location information: “getLatitude()”and “getLongitude()” for a class to my MainActivity automatically and to a DDBB later.
So much thank for any help
this is "the MainActivity" class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView tvlatitud, tvlongitud;
Location location;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tvlongitud = findViewById(R.id.tv_longitud);
    tvlatitud = findViewById(R.id.tv_latitud);
    location = new Location(this);
    askLocation();
}
public void askLocation(){
    location.updateGPS();
}

public void showData(String lat, String lon ){
    tvlatitud.setText(lat);
    tvlongitud.setText(lon);
}
```

and this is the Location class

```
public class Location extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final int PERMISSIONS_FINE_LOCATION = 99;
FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationProviderClient;
LocationRequest locationRequest;
String latitude1, longitude1;
private MainActivity mainActivity;

public Location(MainActivity mainActivity){

    this.mainActivity = mainActivity;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    locationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    locationRequest.setInterval(1000 * 30);
    locationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000 * 50);
    locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    updateGPS();
}
public void updateGPS() {
    fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(Location.this);
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        fusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation().addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<android.location.Location>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(android.location.Location location) {
                updateUIValues(location);
                mainActivity.showData(latitude1, longitude1);
            }
        });
    } else {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,}, PERMISSIONS_FINE_LOCATION);
        }
    }
}
private void updateUIValues(android.location.Location location) {
    latitude1 = String.valueOf(location.getLatitude());
    longitude1 = String.valueOf(location.getLongitude());

}
}
```

Comment: what are you trying to achieve exactly, what do you mean by send location automatically?

Comment: I'm trying to send latitude and longitude data, from Location class to main activity class